# Tag counts on profile page

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

On the profile page under the vote count, what are the tags and the numbers next to them?  Are they how many you have answered for a question with a tag, or how many upvotes, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of questions and answers you've posted in that tag.