# Where do the tags in the tags section of a user's profile come from?

Tags: discussion, tags, profile-page, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Tag counts on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68188/tag-counts-on-profile-page)

I've long been curious: where do the tags in the tags section of a user's profile come from?

For instance, this is the tags section of my profile on MSO.
[image]
Are all these tags from questions I'ved *asked*?  Or *answered*? Or *both*?  Or *what*?

Comment: @Gnome: voted to close also- looks like a close dupe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be coming from both questions you've asked and answered.

Taking a look at [my serverfault profile](https://serverfault.com/users/1309/brandon), I have 17 unique tags. Going through each of my questions and answers, I can see that each question I've asked and answer I've given belong to a different set of tags.

What's a little odd is that I am missing 4 tags from 2 questions, neither of which were ever retagged. Only thing I can think of is that they were asked by unregistered users. Maybe it doesn't count it then.

Comment: BTW, you can check if a user is registered or not on their profile page.

Comment: were those questions migrated?

Comment: @Jeff, ah yes, they were. That would be a better explanation. Shouldn't they still be counted though?