# Tag count calculation on profile page

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

My question has to do with the `Y` component of the `X [tag] x Y` fields under the "Tags" section of my [SO user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573061/c8h10n4o2).

I [believe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68188/tag-counts-on-profile-page?rq=1) that this `Y` is equal to count of questions plus count of answers.  For example, for [python](/questions/tagged/python) I have 11 questions and 11 answers, so Y = 22:

[image]

However, under the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag, I have 60 questions and 151 answers, so I would expect Y=211, but in fact it is 212.

[image]

Is my assumption flawed, or should I just [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

This [seemingly related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114362/tags-count-is-not-updated) seems to do with question score (i.e. net votes), not question count.

(I understand that these calculations are not real-time, but if it's a lag issue the Q and A count must be on a different lag from Q + A.  Also, I didn't recently ask or answer a question on this tag.  **My last answer on this tag was on 20 Oct, my last question on 10 Nov.**)

Comment: did you already wait for 24 hours to see if this resolves itself? The tag/badge calculation scripts don't run on a frequent schedule.

Comment: @rene depends on how you count waiting.  since activity -- yes, see update in bold.  Since noticing the discrepancy, no.  Besides, it's 6-8 weeks, right, not 24 hrs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have, in the `R` tag:

- [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2573061+%5Br%5D+is%3Aq)
- [151 non-wiki answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2573061+%5Br%5D+is%3Aa+wiki%3Ano)
- [1 wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2573061+%5Br%5D+wiki%3Ayes)

so the numbers of 212, 60 and 151 are all correct - the tooltip only mentions **non-wiki** posts.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the mark with my initial answer. The real problem lies in the wiki vs. non-wiki.

Comment: That could explain it, I have exactly [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867135/3d-plot-of-2d-simplex-in-r/35869533#35869533) on the tag.  Thanks for humoring me.